# Add text before TraditionalForm

Tags: output-formatting

Using Print[], I know it is possible to print out "helping text" to better understand a solution:

```
Print["The solution is: ", x]
```

if x holds some value. Now, this text is displayed using typewriter's font and OutputForm (I think: correct me if I'm wrong...). Is it possible, and if so, how, to display this outcome using TraditionalForm for `x` and using non typewriter's font for the text?

```
"The solution is: " x // TraditionalForm
```

doesn't give the desired result, as once `x` holds a value, it is moved to the front of the expression.

Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would work:

```
Text[Row[{"The solution is: ", TraditionalForm[x]}]]
```

You can `Print` the above result, too.